# Tag merge / Synonym request : [coding-standards]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

The following terms are all related and cover the same topic:

[coding-standards](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-standards) x 301
**Wiki**: Coding standards a set of conventions and practices used in software, such as naming classes, variables, and files. 
Programming style is a set of rules or guidelines used when writing the source code for a computer program.

[coding-guideline](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-guideline) x 5 : *No wiki*

[coding-style](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) x 440 : *No wiki*

[code-style](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-style) x 32 : *No wiki*

Comment: I have re-tagged the few that used 
[tag:coding-guideline]