# Coding Style and Coding Standards

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

There was [a post from July 2014 that was partially completed](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6777/tag-merge-synonym-request-coding-standards), but the tags [coding-style](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-style) (543) and [coding-standards](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding-standards) (329) still exist. They appear to be very similar. Should these tags be merged? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these tags should be merged. Merge coding-standards into coding-style, since style is not only larger, but slightly more generic.